# How to use vscode‘s extension jupyter to run on slurm compute node?

Tags: python, jupyter, slurm

I'm trying to use vscode to run jupyter on slurm. It's easy to run on login node. But, as you know, if you run too much on the login node, the administrator will ban your account. So, I will apply for a compute node before I run jupyter:

```
srun -p cpu -n 4 --pty /bin/bash
```

Then, the server will give a node, such as node001.

If I connect to the server with mobaxterm, I can set the node name in tunneling. Then, I can use the compute node to run jupyter.

But how to do this in vscode's jupyter? Is there a way to set the compute node in the extension?

I don't want to run is in a browser. And the server's compute node is not allowed to connect to the publice net.

Answer (score 0):

There is a two-part video ([part one here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u9k6HikDyqk)) that explains at lengths how vscode can be used on HPC clusters. The accompanying GitHub repo is https://github.com/sharcnet/vscode-hpc